# Simplify partial sums of sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n} + n\sqrt{n + 1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum the series

$$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{99}$$

Where  $$a_n =  \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n} + n\sqrt{n + 1}}$$

**Note**: $n= 1, 2, \cdots, 99$

Sorry for the bad formatting but I don't know how to improve it. I would greatly appreciated easy to understand working out and thanks in advance to all :)

Comment: In the denominator in the definition of $A_n$, do you mean $(n+1)\sqrt n + n\sqrt{n+1}$, or have I misunderstood your square roots? For next time, [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tells you more or less anything you should need about writing mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yes you are right about the denominator. Thank you for the helpful guide :)

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

Always the same story : just multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator...

$$a_n=\frac 1{(n+1)\sqrt n + n\sqrt{n+1}} \times\frac{(n+1)\sqrt n - n\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)\sqrt n - n\sqrt{n+1}}$$ hence $$a_n=\frac{ (n+1)\sqrt{n}-n \sqrt{n+1}}{n (n+1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Now, see what is happening.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful hint.
I was wondering how you split the expression into two fractions.  I would greatly appreciated it if you could explain it.

Comment: Split the numerator into the two pieces and now, simplify each fraction remembering that $m=\sqrt m \sqrt m $

Answer (score 0):

I think write following more simple
$$a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: I think my answer is different  and simple to @Mr Claude,@Did,do you agree with me?

Comment: So you factor square roots in the denominator. At most a comment to the already posted answer, no?

Comment: To answer your comment: No.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have kindly pointed out that $$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
There is more to the story though, because I understand you are interested in partial sums. If we consider a partial sum of this sequence:
$$\sum_{n=i}^j a_n = \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}}\bigg) + \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+2}}\bigg) + \dots + \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}\bigg)$$
$$\sum_{n=i}^j a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} - \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}}\bigg) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+2}} + \dots + \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}\bigg)$$
Conveniently, the '$(n+1)$' component of one term cancels with the '$(n)$' term of the next, and the sum collapses quite nicely. (Hence why the call this a telescoping series).
$$\sum_{n=i}^j a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}$$